# SSIS - CSV to SQL Server Data Import Error

Tags: csv, ssis

I'm trying and playing around a CSV file to import data into the SQL Server table using SSIS.
The package is simple with File Source Task and SQL Server Destination.

The CSV file has 2 fields Transaction_Date and Account_Created. The dates in these fields are the format of 1/2/2009  6:00:00 AM. I am seeing the below error message:
"Error: An exception has occurred during data insertion, the message returned from the provider is: The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type datetime of the specified target column."

Steps I tried below:
I tried using various other destination transformations.
I tried playing around the Data Types inside the Flatfile Connection Managers.
I tried using the Data Conversion Transformations between the Source Task and SQL Server Destination.

When I tried to load the data by providing connection only to Transaction_Date it works. However, when I tried to load by providing connection only to Account_Created it fails.

I am sure I'm missing something silly. Please help.

Regards,
KK

I tired a different method to build the package from start using the Wizard. I used the actual CSV file which had many other columns like Price, Product_name and so on. When I tried to execute the package I see a different error message as below: 
"[Destination for AdventureWorks [58]] Error: There was an error with input column "Price" (91) on input "OLE DB Destination Input" (71). The column status returned was: "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".
"
When I tried a CSV file with only 2 date fields it worked excellent.

I am really puzzled now and thinking this is some kind of data type issues which I am not getting it correct. Can some one pls shred some light into this problem?

Regards,
KK

Comment: You definitely need to use a data conversion transformation. Does 1/2/2009 mean 1st Feb or 2nd Jan? As an example, the SSIS expression `(DT_DBDATE) "2009-01-02"` results in a date. You need to perform some string manipulation on your data file to get your date into that format and then use (DT_DBDATE) to convert it to a date data type.

Answer (score 2):

To load the first two fields (Transaction_Date, Account_Created), you need a DataFlow Task that contains:

- Flatfile Source
- Derived Column (create two columns to Replace 'Transaction_Date' and 'Account_Created' with formula below)
- SQL Server Destination

Notes:

- Date format like '1/2/2009 6:00:00 AM' is not parsed by SSIS, make sure the Flatfile Connection Manager treats the fields as Strings (length > 22)
- In Derived Column, you can parse '01/02/2009' with this formula:

  (DT_DBDATE)(SUBSTRING([Column 2],7,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING([Column 2],4,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING([Column 2],1,2))
- The current date format that you have in the file '1/2/2009' makes the conversion very tricky due to the lack of advanced datetime parsing functions of SSIS. Depending on the day and month you will have to subtract from a variable length string, therefore you will have to combine SUBSTRING with FINDSTRING to determine the position of the separator '/'

Good luck